# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_36 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 50)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, valueerror

## model gru

```
model_gru = Sequential()

model_gru.add(GRU(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 1), return_sequences=True))
model_gru.add(BatchNormalization())
model_gru.add(Dropout(0.2))

model_gru.add(GRU(64, activation='relu'))
model_gru.add(BatchNormalization())
model_gru.add(Dropout(0.2))

model_gru.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model_gru.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))

print(model_gru.summary())
```

This is my model and I'm getting the error

```
model_gru.load_weights(r"C:\Users\Admin/gru_model.h5")
q_test_gru = model_gru.predict(test_data, verbose=0)
y_test_gru = q_test_gru.argmax(1)
```

Could you help in resolving the error as there is some issue with the size of input ?

Answer (score 0):

The first layer should be defined as follows:

```
model_gru.add(GRU(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(50,), return_sequences=True))
```

Comment: Still this error is coming - ValueError: Input 0 of layer gru_28 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 50)

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error you are getting in the question ? It helps me as well as others who might be able to help you